# In ADS, why am I getting such a strange output when sweeping a variable and graphing it?

Tags: ads

I am trying to get the gain of this circuit vs. capacitance. Here is a screenshot of my circuit and results.

Why is the result behaving like this? It should just be one line. Why are there so many lines?

[image]

Comment: You're sure you didn't change the 'step' parameter in the sweep between when you did the simulation and when you took the screenshot?

Comment: @ThePhoton I didn't change anything after taking the screenshot. It's giving me the same problem on a different circuit.

Comment: What happens if you plot it the usual way (db(S(2,1)) as a function of f)

Comment: @ThePhoton Plotting it vs. frequency gives me several overlaid lines, which I surmise represent varying capacitance values.

Comment: It should give exactly 10 lines. If it gives something different, that would be interesting added information.